# Prepaid data simcard for balkan countries

Tags: bulgaria, montenegro, macedonia, kosovo

What are the options for prepaid data sim cards to use in the Balkan states (Kosovo, Montenegro, Macedonia)?

Will it be cheaper to buy local sim cards in each country or is there any company that has offers for the internet in other balkan countries?

I'll be staying 1-2 days in each country so it would be a lot more convenient to use a single card.

Comment: Kris, I took the freedom to change a bit the question removing the word "good" here and there. Travel.SE policy is to avoid giving suggestions over shopping, and to avoid question asking for personal opinion (what is "good" for you could not be "good" for someone else).

Answer (score 2):

The Wiki on http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Prepaid_SIM_with_data has a good overview over options in different countries. Due to the political situation there won't be a "one covers all" option, but you have to pick different cards and/or do roaming. Which to choose heavily depends on your requirements ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused from the use of the tag "bulgaria", as you don't mention it in the question body.

Anyway, M-Tel offers a roaming package over Montenegro, Macedonia and Kosovo. I have no idea how cheap and/or economically convenient it can be, but given the prices here in Bulgaria and the general economy in this part of Europe, I'd guess it shouldn't that much expensive.

Comment: I'll start journey from Bulgaria, so i tagged it just in case.